# GSON converter android

Tags: android, retrofit, gson

Есть JSON строка которая приходит с сервера, в ней находятся поля которые могут находиться в различных состояниях, к примеру при первом запросе c сервера может вернуться JSON типа:

```
"user":{"is_new":false,"user_id":390,"need_fields":["name","last_name","email"]}
```

При повторном запросе:

```
"user":{"is_new":false,"user_id":390,"need_fields":"false"}
```

Подскажите, как конвертировать подобные ответы от сервера в `UserObject`

Comment: Правильным было бы, заставить привести разработчиков серверной части ответы в порядок. Иначе этот "динамический" рай веб-девелопмента превращается в ад для мобильных клиентов со статической типизацией.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще это какая-то плохая практика. Не знаю какие у вас значения могут быть, но если только список и "false", то лучше вместо "false" использовать например пустой список. Или же просто опускать поле "need_fields" и вместо него другие поля создать и использовать.

Если же без таких костылей никак не обойтись, то пишите свою логику десериализации для конкретного объекта:

```
public static final Gson GSON = new GsonBuilder()
        .registerTypeAdapter(User.class, new UserAdapter())
        .create();

private static class UserAdapter implements JsonDeserializer<User> {

    @Override
    public User deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) {
        //
        //логика парсинга из JsonElement
        //
    }
```

Comment: Это не "какая-то" практика, это скорее всего ад PHP :)

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja, к счастью, не приходилось с таким сталкиваться до сих пор

Comment: Спасибо за моральную поддержку:) Пришлось разбирать всё через ResponseBody и доставать каждую строку отдельно